# Get all objects that belongs to a entity in a one-to-many relationship with core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I'm working on simple iPhone app and I'm trying to get core data working. I currently have two entities in my data model, it looks like this:

[image: Data relationsship]

In my application I have a tableview that should display all pages that belongs to a certain note block. I currently use:

```
NoteblockAppController * appController = [NoteblockAppController sharedNoteblockAppController];
NSArray * list = [appController allInstancesOf:@"Page" orderBy:@"createdAt"];
noteblockPages = [list mutableCopy];
```

But this obviously doesn't work since it always shows the same pages. I assume that I have to fetch the result some other way, but I don't know how.

I'm quite stuck so any tips/tricks would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: The code you've provided calls two custom methods which aren't shown so we have no idea what the codes does or what you expect to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to add derived methods to access things like this.  I add these to the custom class but don't model them in the data model.

Once you get your accessor working correctly, it should return a mutable set.  Then:

```
- (NSArray *)noteblockPagesArray {
  NSMutableSet *pages = self.noteblockPages;
  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"createdAt" ascending:YES];

  NSArray *orderedPages = [pages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
  return orderedPages;
}
```

Modify to cache value as appropriate/needed.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a clean solution. Will try it once I solved my accessor problem.

Comment: It turned out that the property did get set, I just had to move the NSLog statement to viewWillAppear instead of my init method.

Answer (score 1):

Let CoreData do the work. You have an instance of the Noteblock, correct?

```
[yourNoteblock noteblockPages]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have a instance variable and property called pagesNoteblock that's an instance of Noteblock in my second tableview. I try to set that instance like this in my previous tableview (that is a AQGridView, gridView) in: `- (AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    PagesTableViewController * pagesController = [[PagesTableViewController alloc] init];    
    Noteblock * selectedNoteblock = [noteblockList objectAtIndex:index];
    [pagesController setPagesNoteblock:selectedNoteblock];`
    
But it doesn't work. The instance isn't getting set.

Comment: I'd focus the effort on finding out why that isn't getting set rather than doing a new query. You might want to pose that as a new question with the relevant bits of code. Good luck.